# Powershell MediaInfo read files in dir

Tags: powershell, mediainfo

I'm somewhat of a Powershell newbie, I've been using PS purposefully as my main scripting language for about 6 months now.

I'm trying to generate a basic script using only powershell and mediainfo to parse details from files in a directory (input) to another directory (output) of individual .txt files (Ideally with original file extensions removed).

The source and output filename should be the same, eg: `test.mp4 -> test.txt`.
Here is what I've managed so far:

```
$indir = "C:\Temp\input"
$outdir = "C:\Temp\output\"
$mediainfo = "C:\Temp\MediaInfo_CLI_x64\MediaInfo.exe "

$files = Get-ChildItem $indir

foreach ($file in $files )
    {
    Write-Host "Scanning " $file.FullName
    Start-Process $mediainfo $file.FullName -NoNewWindow | out-file $outdir $file.Name
    }
```

I'm running into a lot of issues, and I feel like the solution is quite simple.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: My script above cant seem to capture the output correctly at this point. The script posted originally errors on the out-file, but I changed the last line to:
`Start-Process $mediainfo $file.FullName -NoNewWindow | out-file "$outdir\$file.Name.txt"`
Now I get empty .txt files and the output in the console inself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Start-Process`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) has parameters for redirecting STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, so try this:

```
Start-Process $mediainfo $file.FullName -NoNewWindow -Wait `
    -RedirectStandardOutput "$outdir\$($file.Name).txt"
```

Normally you'd launch external programs with the call operator (`&`), though, which should let you use the regular output streams:

```
& $mediainfo $file.FullName | Out-File "$outdir\$($file.Name).txt"
```

If the program doesn't write to the success output stream (STDOUT) you can redirect the other streams like this (see [about_Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) for details):

```
& $mediainfo $file.FullName *>&1 | Out-File "$outdir\$($file.Name).txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but I still get the same thing; empty text files and all output in console.
I'm using PS v3.

Is the problem because I'm using `Start-Process` to launch MediaInfo? Perhaps there is a more sensible way to call the exe that I am not aware of?

Comment: This is great, thanks!
I didnt think to check if there were output parameters specific to `Start-Process`.

The following simplified code works:
`Start-Process $mediainfo $file.FullName -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput "$outdir\$file.txt"`

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have compiled a DLL wrapper for MediaInfo so you can use it in PowerShell like this

```
add-type -path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\vise_mediainfo.dll'
$MediaInfo = New-Object VISE_MediaInfo.MediaInfo
#Display all codec info about this PC
$MediaInfo.Option("Info_Codecs")
#Display information about a specific file
$MediaInfo.Open('C:\Users\username\Videos\video_name.mp4')
$MediaInfo.Inform()
```

Download from https://ianmorrish.wordpress.com/v-ise/mediainfo/

Comment: Thanks! This was some time ago I was looking into this, but I'm definitely going to revisit.